# How to use a variable inside the range function?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

How do I make this a function so that I can pass "B38" as a variable?

I tried putting `startCell` inside the range function.

```vb
Set startCell = Range("B38")
For i = 0 To 6
    hourVal = Worksheets("Expense & Hours").Range("b38").Offset(0, i).Value
    dateVal = Worksheets("Expense & Hours").Range("b38").Offset(2, i).Value
    MsgBox "Current: " & hourVal & "  " & dateVal
Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
Dim addr As String

addr = "B38"

Set startCell = Worksheets("Expense & Hours").Range(addr)
For i = 0 To 6
    hourVal = startCell.Offset(0, i).Value
    dateVal = startCell.Offset(2, i).Value
    MsgBox "Current: " & hourVal & "  " & dateVal
Next i
```